# touchUpInside event for uibutton under transparent uiview

Tags: uiview, uibutton

I've uibutton under transparent uiview, how can I determine touchUpInside event?

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `userInteractionEnabled` of the transparent UIView to NO and it should pass all touches to your UIButtons.